# Sizing an Azure Geo Replicated Database

Tags: azure, database-replication, azure-sql-database

If I have an S2 Sql Database, and I create a secondary geo-replicated database, should it be of the same size (S2)? I see that you get charged for the secondary DB, but the DTU's reported against that secondary are 0%, which seems to indicate that S2 is too large.

Obviously, we'd like to save the cost if at all possible and move the secondary to a smaller size if at all possible.

**Considerations**

I understand if we need to failover to the secondary, at that point, it would need to be bumped up to the size of S2 to meet the production workloads, but assuming that we could do this at the time of failover?

I also get that if we were actively using the replicated DB for reporting, etc, then we'd have to size it accordingly to meet that demand. But currently, we are not actively using the secondary for anything other than to use as a failover point if it is ever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point both primary and secondary must be in the same edition but can have different performance objectives (DTU size). We are working on lifting that limitation so that geo-replication databases could scale to a different edition when needed without breaking the replication links (e.g. standard to premium).

Re sizing the secondary, you *can" make it smaller in DTU than the primary if you believe that the updates take less capacity than reads (high read/write ratio). But as noted earlier, you will have to upsize it right after the failover and it may take time during which your app's performance  will be impacted. In general, we do not recommend having the secondary more than 1 level smaller. E.g. S3->S1 is not a good idea as it will likely cause replication lag and may result in excessive data loss after failover.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely change the tier of the secondary database, but bear in mind, that in the case of failover, you will face performance issues. Also you cant scale past your current performance Tier (so both bases ought to be of the same Tier).

And yes, you can change the size past failover, but the process is manual.

Comment: Can you clarify "Also you cant scale past your current performance Tier (so both bases ought to be of the same Tier)"? I'm guessing you mean that I shouldn't make the secondary be in a tier lower than the primary as if I need to failover to it, and assuming the primary is sized such that it needs to be in the Standard Tier and wouldn't perform well in the Basic tier, if the secondary was sized to be in the Basic tier, I wouldn't be able to scale it back up to the Standard Tier. So the lowest size I should go would be down to an S0 in this case.

Comment: yes, Azure won't allow you to scale from S to B or to P.